# How can I apply multiple conditions to decide what values are written from an array to a target destination?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

In an effort to streamline my efforts for a data transfer macro, I have moved to arrays. I have limited experience with them, let alone vba. But I was able to build it, and have it write. The last hurdle I have is that I am unable to specify which values to write, as I only need them transferred if they are over or under a certain amount; i.e. array(dem2, 6) = >300 write, array(dem2, 6) = <300 don't write.

Long story short, I want to be able to write data for rows where that value is either >300 or <-300.

I spent several hours reading posts, trying various loops and conditions including do, do while, goto, elseif but none seem to work and cause errors to pop up.

```
Public wbFr As Workbook
Public wbTo As Workbook
Public wsFr As Worksheet
Public wsTo As Worksheet
Option Explicit
Public Sub MoveToLogBookArray()
'==================================
' Macro to put data in array      '
' Then write to separate workbook '
'==================================
Dim FromArr() As Variant
Dim Dem1 As Long, Dem2 As Long  'Multi-dimensional
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim test As Boolean
'==================
'Workbook with data
Set wbFr = Workbooks("Book1useV2.xlsm")
'====================
'Destination workbook
Set wbTo = Workbooks("Book2V2.xlsm")
'============
'Source sheet
Set wsFr = wbFr.Worksheets("test")
'=================
'Destination sheet
Set wsTo = wbTo.Worksheets("Sheet7")

With wsFr               'Attempt at setting bounds of array
Dem1 = Range("A2:A10").Cells.Count - 1  '# of rows
Dem2 = Range("A2:A10").Cells.Count - 3  '# of columns
    ReDim FromArr(0 To Dem1, 0 To Dem2)
        For Dem1 = LBound(FromArr, 1) To UBound(FromArr, 1)
            For Dem2 = LBound(FromArr, 2) To UBound(FromArr, 2)
                FromArr(Dem1, Dem2) = wsFr.Range("A2").Offset(Dem1, Dem2)
            Next Dem2
        Next Dem1
    End With
    'Successfully builds array
    '=========================
    'Find last row of destination sheet to go to next empty row
With wsTo
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).row
    Else
        lastRow = 1
    End If
End With
'================================================================
With wsTo
    j = lastRow + 1
      For i = LBound(FromArr) To UBound(FromArr)

        test = True

        If FromArr(Dem2, 6) <= 300 Then test = False    'Inputting .value gives error
            'do nothing                                 '"Object required"
        If FromArr(Dem2, 6) >= 300 Then test = True

        If test = False Then
            wsTo.Cells(j, 1) = FromArr(i, 0)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 2) = FromArr(i, 1)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 3) = FromArr(i, 2)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 4) = FromArr(i, 3)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 10) = FromArr(i, 4)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 13) = FromArr(i, 5)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 17) = FromArr(i, 6)
            j = j + 1
        End If              '=======================================================
        Next i              'I'm unable to write only values over 300 or under -300]
End With                    '=======================================================

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

As mentioned above, I want to be able to specify rows of values input into an array in one workbook, then write them to a separate workbook based on conditions of column 6.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
With wsTo   'set break here
    j = lastRow + 1
      For i = LBound(FromArr) To UBound(FromArr)
        test = (FromArr(Dem2, 6) <= -300) And (FromArr(Dem2, 6) >= 300) '= True/False
                                        'tried both false/true and commented out^^^^^                                
                                        'and flipping <, >
            If test = True Then
                'do nothing
            End If
                    'When it writes, it writes all values or no values at all
                    '````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
            If test = False Then          'values for 4&5 include decimals
                wsTo.Cells(j, 1) = FromArr(i, 0)    'type= variant/double
                wsTo.Cells(j, 2) = FromArr(i, 1)    'type= variant/string
                wsTo.Cells(j, 3) = FromArr(i, 2)    'type= variant/string
                wsTo.Cells(j, 4) = FromArr(i, 3)    'type= variant/string
                wsTo.Cells(j, 10) = FromArr(i, 4)   'type= variant/double
                wsTo.Cells(j, 13) = FromArr(i, 5)   'type= variant/double
                wsTo.Cells(j, 17) = FromArr(i, 6)   'type= variant/double
                j = j + 1    'On 4th iteration, value is 285 but is written anyway
            End If
                            '=======================================================
        Next i              'I'm unable to write only values over 300 or under -300]
End With                    '=======================================================

Exit Sub
'Values in test Column
'517.34
'733.68
'312.26
'285.00 writes regardless
'297.00 ""
'312.00
'333.00
'250.00 ""
'500.00
End Sub
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

And here is my finished working project thanks to Robert and Patrick.

```
Public wbFr As Workbook
Public wbTo As Workbook
Public wsFr As Worksheet
Public wsTo As Worksheet
Option Explicit
Public Sub MoveToLogBookArray()
'==================================
' Macro to put data in array      '
' Then write to separate workbook '
'==================================
Dim FromArr() As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim test As Boolean
'==================
'Workbook with data
Set wbFr = Workbooks("Book1useV2.xlsm")
'====================
'Destination workbook
Set wbTo = Workbooks("Book2V2.xlsm")
'============
'Source sheet
Set wsFr = wbFr.Worksheets("test")
'=================
'Destination sheet
Set wsTo = wbTo.Worksheets("Sheet7")
'========================================================================
With wsFr               'Attempt at setting bounds of array
    FromArr = Range("adjRange")
End With

With wsTo
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).row
    Else
        lastRow = 1
    End If
End With
'===================================================================
'Be sure to verify parameters
'Check for errors
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
With wsTo
    j = lastRow + 1
      For i = LBound(FromArr) To UBound(FromArr)

      test = False

        If FromArr(i, 6) >= 300 And FromArr(i, 6) <= -300 Then test = False
        If FromArr(i, 6) < 299.99 And FromArr(i, 6) > -299.99 Then test = True

            If test = False Then
                wsTo.Cells(j, 1) = FromArr(i, 1)
                wsTo.Cells(j, 2) = FromArr(i, 2)
                wsTo.Cells(j, 3) = FromArr(i, 3)
                wsTo.Cells(j, 4) = FromArr(i, 4)
                wsTo.Cells(j, 10) = FromArr(i, 5)
                wsTo.Cells(j, 13) = FromArr(i, 6)
                wsTo.Cells(j, 17) = FromArr(i, 7)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
End With
On Error GoTo 0
'===================================================================
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred! Please check values are in correct column. " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you know how to set breakpoints when debugging in the Excel VBA editor, right? So, by stepping through your code, you should be able to see what's wrong,

Comment: @RobertBaron yes, everything works except specifying rows to write(last if statement). It writes them all when I would want to set parameters for which ones write.

Comment: If all rows are written, then test is always `False`, which means `FromArr(Dem2, 6) <= 300` is always `True`. In the debugger, does `FromArr()` contain the conditions you want in column 6? That should be straightforward to see in the debugger.

Comment: @RobertBaron yes, fromarr(i, 6) for one iteration = 312.26, while another iteration = 285. And no matter which way i flip the >= it still writes them all, or none at all. Test value changes to true on pass through, and will not write when false. I'm not sure I'm using them correctly.--------apologies, it won't write if statement FromArr(dem2, 6) >= then test = false

Comment: Based on how you use boolean *test*, it should be `test = (FromArr(Dem2, 6) >= -300) And (FromArr(Dem2, 6) <= 300)`

Comment: `FromArr()` is of type `Variant` which means it can contain any type. When comparing to `300`, make sure `FromArr(Dem2, 6)` contains a number type. The debugger tells you the underlying type of a `Variant`. If not of type number, there are VBA functions to convert to number.

Comment: @RobertBaron `FromArr(Dem2, 6)` contains variant/double type.

Comment: @PatricK I tried this, or at least as I understood it, to no avail. I used it multiple ways, changing stuff around, but was never able to get it to exclude any values from being written.

Comment: @sTan_The_mAn The boolean operation in my previous comment works if you are to omit values from `-300 <= x <= 300`. In your *working* code, get rid of `FromArr(i, 6) >= 300 And FromArr(i, 6) <= -300` (how can a number be greater then 300 and less than negative 300 at the same time?). You can get rid of those If blocks if you use code as per my previous comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do I declare `x As Double` then use it in place of `test`? How would this look? And in the process of testing this, I have discovered that it will not write more than 7 rows. I didn't have a lot more rows than that when testing and they were under 300 so I didn't pay it any mind. But when I added more, I found it was stopping without checking them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You had a typo in the index to the `FromArr()`. I could not run it, so let me know if it does not work.

```
With wsTo
    j = lastRow + 1
    For i = LBound(FromArr, 1) To UBound(FromArr2, 1)

        If FromArr(i, 6) <= 300 Then test = False
        If FromArr(1, 6) > 300 Then test = True

        If test = False Then
            wsTo.Cells(j, 1) = FromArr(i, 0)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 2) = FromArr(i, 1)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 3) = FromArr(i, 2)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 4) = FromArr(i, 3)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 10) = FromArr(i, 4)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 13) = FromArr(i, 5)
            wsTo.Cells(j, 17) = FromArr(i, 6)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I had to change it to `Lbound(FromArr, 1) to UBound(FromArr, 2)` , but I got the jist of what you were trying to say. In addition I wasn't attaching my true/ false parameters correctly. Thank you sir.